# Passing model values to views MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model, view

I am in need of how the correct way to do this.

1. I can not use forms authentication
2. A user will "login" or confirm identity based on a value

I need to walk the user through a series of pages like so

1. Contact/MailAddress
2. Contact/Phone
3. Contact/Email
4. Contact/Summary
5. Questionaire/Question1
6. Questionaire/Question2
7. Questionaire/Question3
8. Questionaire/Summary
9. Final/Certify
10. Final/Review

I plan on using Session to hold the data but I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass the values to other views and how Redirect to other pages.

Any help will do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have some models like this

```
public class ContactModel 
{
    public string MailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionaireModel
{
    public string Question1Answer { get; set; }
    public string Question2Answer { get; set; }
    public string Question3Answer { get; set; }
}

public class ContactQuestionaireModel
{
    public ContactModel Contact { get; set; }
    public QuestionaireModel Question { get; set; }
}
```

and you want to persist this model from view to view and action to action. In you controller you can create 2 actions.  one for your first view and one for your second

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ContactAddress()
{
    var model = new ContactQuestionaireModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactAddress(ContactQuestionaireModel model)
{
    var currentModel = TempData["currentModel"] as ContactQuestionaireModel;
    currentModel.Contact.MailAddress = model.Contact.MailAddress;
    TempData["currentModel"] = currentModel;
    return RedirectToAction("ContactPhone");
}

public ActionResult ContactPhone()
{
    var model = TempData["currentModel"] as ContactQuestionaireModel;
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactPhone(ContactQuestionaireModel model)
{
    var currentModel = TempData["currentModel"] as ContactQuestionaireModel;
    currentModel.Contact.Phone = model.Contact.Phone;
    TempData["currentModel"] = currentModel;
    return RedirectToAction("ContactEmail");
}
```

in the first action `ContactAddress` you create a new blank model and pass that in to your view `ContactAddress`. In that view you can set TempData["currentModel"] equal to the model you are passing in. This will stay in TempData for 1 post back to the server.  You dont need to do this on the first page since it's blank anyway but i'm doing it to save time.

**View ContactAddress**

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.ContactQuestionaireModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact Address";
    TempData["currentModel"] = Model; //this will be available to me in the HttpPost action
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Contact.MailAddress, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Contact.MailAddress, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

you'll notice in the controller code that the Post Action for `ContactAddress` is setting a var `currentModel` equal to what is in TempData["currentModel"] which was set in the `ContactAddress` view.  Before you do a redirect to the next action `ContactPhone` set `TempData["currentModel"]` back to the model you are building and use it in the next action.

You do have the option of adding the Model as a parameter to each action and passing the `currentModel` object like

```
public ActionResult ContactPhone(ContactQuestionaireModel model)
return RedirectToAction("ContactPhone", currentModel);
```

its up to you really. this is not a foolproof way. page refreshes and back and forward buttons could clear out everything that was entered.  Storing the information in `Session` or actually saving the data in a database might be more optimal.

Comment: This works great... but how do I handle partial validation of the model... if mailaddress is filled out on Contact/MailAddress yet the Phone is required how do you handle that??

Comment: you can always validate server side and pass model errors back to the view if need be.  you would just have an if statement and `return RedirectToAction` if valid or just return `View(model)` if invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I advise against doing what you are attempting to do by logging in with session but what you are looking for is:

```
TempData.yourModel = new SomeModel { Data = "yourData" };

//next page
var model = (SomeModel)TempData.yourModel;
```

and

```
RedirectToAction("yourController", "yourAction");
```

Comment: when using the redirecttoaction function how do you maintain the model??? or do I store the model in a viewbag

Comment: Either store the model in the ViewBag and cast it back out in the next page or do this to append data on the url: return RedirectToAction("yourController","yourAction", new { FirstName="John", LastName="Doe"});

Comment: you need to use TempData if you're sending data to another action using RedirectToAction

Comment: ViewBag will be null after the redirect

Comment: should I make an action with a model as a parameter?

Comment: IE... 

`code`
function foo(model as mymodel)
end 
`code`

Comment: also how would I know the model is the current model? 

say the user inserts data into Contact/MailAddress and I redirect to Contact/Phone. How would phone know it was a redirect or a postback?

Comment: If you are getting the model from TempData then it is a redirect, otherwise just use HttpPost and handle the model in the post back.