# Simple Wizard which needs to save the data at every step

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Before going into detail I just want to summarize what I am trying to do. I want to create multiple forms which acts like a Wizard with Next and Previous Button. I want to save the data for each step when the user click Next key so that I don't have to save the data temporary in the Session or hidden fields. My database structure is such that I have one Main table and all the Wizard Steps are child of the Main Table. Main Table has one to many relationship with child tables. Main Table does not have any View associated with it. Kindly look at the detail below and if you can then suggest some guideline and add direction to what I am doing.

This might be not very complex but as new to the Entity Frmework and MVC I am yet to find a way to achieve it.

Lets say I have four simple models,

```
public class MainModel
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Column(TypeName = "bigint")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public Child1 Child1 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Child2> Child2 { get; set; }
}

public class Child1
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Column(TypeName = "bigint")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string BioData { get; set; }

    public int MainModelID { get; set; }

    public MainModel MainModel { get; set; }
}

public class Child2
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Column(TypeName = "bigint")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }

    public int MainModelID { get; set; }

    public MainModel MainModel { get; set; }
}
```

I have two Views for Child1 and Child2. MainModel does not have any view because it does not have any fields which needs to be taken input from the user.

In the Controller I have following methods,

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
        return View("Child1View", new Child1());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessChild1(Child1 model)
{
        If (Model.IsValid)
        {
             // Save the Child1 model to the database
             // If it is first time the first MainModel needs to b saved
             // How to determine whether Child1 was already saved so that next time update it?
             // I don't want to use session or hidden fields to store complete objects because of size so I am saving each Child at each step
        }
}


[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Child2()
{
        return View("Child2View", new Child2());
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessChild2(Child2 model)
{
        If (Model.IsValid)
        {
             // Save the Child2 model to the database
             // As Child1 will be already saved so MainModel will be already created too but should I need to store MainModel in Session?
        }
}
```

Now kindly don't consider this the actual code. This code is just to give the idea what I am doing and what I have done so far so there can be few mistakes in the sample code. What I want is that when Child3View is submitted and ProcessChild1 Action method is called then create the MainModel and insert Child1 model with it and Same goes for the ProcessChild2 Action method. I have not mentioned any views because this is just the sample code.

Also I plan to have next and previous buttons on the Views so that I can navigate between the Child1View and Child2View. This creates another confusion that first  time the MainModel will be created but if the User goes back by clicking Previous button and click Next again then the record is updated instead of inserted.

It would be also great if someone knows about any example online regarding this.

Comment: @Felix Castor Frankly I don't understand your comment completely. I know about the foreign key but unable to understand what do you mean by "Why don't you have a Child table that contains two columns for ID". Ho w come this is two to many relationship? One to many in MainModel to Child1 and One to many in MainModel to Child2. I was just looking for logic in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to determine whether Child1 was already saved so that next time
>   update it?

you should have a `@Html.HiddenFor(child1 => child1.Id)` in you `Child1` view and it should get passed to `ProcessChild1` action.  If `model.Id == 0` then it's a new record.

> should I need to store MainModel in Session

same goes for `MainModel`.  include a hidden `MainModel.Id` field in your views.  make sure you populate the `Child1.MainModel` property or `Child2.MainModel` whenever you create the `MainModel` entity

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessChild1(Child1 model)
{
    if (Model.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.Id == 0)
        {
            //create MainModel
            var mainModel = new MainModel();
            //attach new Child1
            mainModel.Child1 = new Child1();
            //save changes
            context.MainModels.Add(mainModel);
            context.SaveChanges();
            model.MainModel = mainModel;
        }
        else
        { 
            //find Child1 by ID
            var Child1 = context.Child1.Find(model.Id);
            //update Child1
            //save changes
            model.MainModel = Child1.MainModel;
        }
        return View("Child2View", new Child2() { MainModel = model.MainModel }); 
    }
    return View("Child1View", model);
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply. Can you please elaborate the use of model.MainModel = mainModel. I can understand the mainModel.Child1 = new Child1 but not the model.MainModel = mainModel. Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: `model` should have a `MainModel`  property so it's just using that property so you can set the `MainModel` property of the `new Child2()` model that you're passing to your `Child2View`  so in your view you can create a hidden for the ID so you dont have to store anything in session..

Comment: just one more quick question. What you have suggested is absolutely perfect for me when passing entity models to the view. What if I have different Entity Models and View Models. In View Models how can I assign the MainModel to the Child View Model as I know that it is a bad practice to use Entity models in the View Models. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Also what could be the best way to access Child1 model values in Child2 controller?

Comment: see if this helps you any http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682856/passing-model-values-to-views-mvc-5/31684161#31684161

Comment: MainModel should have all the properties you need.. just copy the classes and rename them to MainModelViewModel, Child1ViewModel, etc..